# Unable to change image from UIImageView

Tags: ios, objective-c, uiimageview, nsmutablearray

I have an NSMutableArray with some UIImageView's inside. After a scroll action I want to change the images of some UIImageView but I can't.

This is how I first initiate the Array:

```
NSMutableArray *dotsImageSliderList = [[NSMutableArray alloc]init];

for (int i=0; i<totalImages; i++)
{
   UIImageView *dot =[[UIImageView alloc] initWithFrame:CGRectMake(distance,2,5,5)];
   if (i==0)
   {
       dot.image=[UIImage imageNamed:@"dotselected.png"];
   }
   else
   {
       dot.image=[UIImage imageNamed:@"dotunselected.png"];
   }

   [dotsImageSliderList addObject:dot];
}
```

And this is how I retrieve the UIImageView's and trying to change the images:

```
-(void)scrollViewDidEndScrollingAnimation:(UIScrollView *)scrollView
{
    [NSObject cancelPreviousPerformRequestsWithTarget:self];
    NSInteger pagenumber = scrollView.contentOffset.x / scrollView.bounds.size.width;
    NSLog(@"%zd", pagenumber);

    if (pagenumber < [dotsImageSliderList count])
    {
        for (int i=0; i<[dotsImageSliderList count]; i++)
        {
            UIImageView *view = [dotsImageSliderList objectAtIndex:pagenumber];
            if (i==pagenumber)
            {
                view.image=[UIImage imageNamed:@"dotselected.png"];
            }
            else
            {
                view.image=[UIImage imageNamed:@"dotunselected.png"];
            }
        }
    }
}
```

I have no idea why the images don't change. Can you spot the mistake?

Answer (score 0):

Initialise image object outside the loop.

```
    NSMutableArray *dotsImageSliderList = [[NSMutableArray alloc]init];
    UIImage * selectedImage = [UIImage imageNamed:@"dotselected.png"];
    UIImage * unselectedImage = [UIImage imageNamed:@"dotunselected.png"];

    for (int i=0; i<totalImages; i++)
    {
       UIImageView *dot =[[UIImageView alloc] initWithFrame:CGRectMake(distance,2,5,5)];
       if (i==0)
       {
           dot.image=selectedImage;
       }
       else
       {
           dot.image=unselectedImage;
       }

       [dotsImageSliderList addObject:dot];
    }
```

Answer (score 0):

Super silly mistake. I have to change this line:

```
UIImageView *view = [dotsImageSliderList objectAtIndex:pagenumber];
```

to this:

```
UIImageView *view = [dotsImageSliderList objectAtIndex:i];
```